# Materialize. Get access to autocomplete element properties

Tags: properties, autocomplete, materialize

I guess answer should be easy, but I´m going mad trying to find an answer.

Let´s say that I have a Materialize autocomplete element defined like this.

```js
 $('#element_id).autocomplete({
                limit:5,
                data:{"a":null,"b":null,"c":null},
                onAutocomplete:function(){whatEverYouWannaDoAfterCompletion()}
            });
```

However, getting the selected value has no problem, my question is...
Is it possible to get selected index with activeIndex autocomplete item property or should I "navigate" throught rendered component to find the selected ocurrence?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although the final goal is not clear for me, I'll try to clarify at least how access the property **activeIndex** and some more.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').autocomplete({
    data: {
      a: null,
      b1: null,
      b2: null
    }
  });
  
  function checkIndex() {
    var el = $('input').get(0);
    var instance = M.Autocomplete.getInstance(el);
    console.log(instance.count, instance.activeIndex, $('input').val());
    setTimeout(checkIndex, 333);
  }
  
  checkIndex();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="container input-field">
  <input class="autocomplete">
</div>
```

Here I prepared a time-driven function to check properties with no dependency on the element focus. The key step is to get the element instance in Materialize space (not jQuery!).

As for the properties sense understanding, I think we should test them carefully before using. In my tests I have seen the only `activeIndex=-1` value even if the selection match the option value entirely. The expected behavior is different to my mind.